# invalid type argument of unary '*'

Tags: c

I'm a week into an intro programming class, and I'm having trouble with fixing what's supposed to be a relatively simple code. I keep getting an invalid type argument of unary '*' error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159; 
int main()
{
   float r;
   float area;
   scanf("%f", &r);
   area = PI * r * r;
   printf("Area is %f", area);
   return 0; 
}
```

Could someone explain this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#define PI 3.14159; 
                  ^
```

Drop the semicolon. Leaving it in, the code will expand to:

```
area = 3.14159; * r * r;
```

Comment: Or better yet, stop using #define.

Comment: @RobertAleksanderYevdokimov Don't `#define PI 3.14159`, in first place. `#include <math.h>` and use `M_PI`. Generally: don't reinvent the wheel, use the standard library whenever possible.

Comment: `M_PI` isn't part of standard C, is it?

Comment: Indeed it isn't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007925/using-m-pi-with-c89-standard

Comment: @CarlNorum **Must not**. Didn't think of that :-)

Comment: @RyanAmos: What's wrong with using a macro where none is needed is that it circumvents the language, opening up weird errors like this. If the OP had instead written `const float PI = 3.14159f;`, this question wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the extra `;` in the definition of the macro `PI`. It is unnecessary for macro, and in your case results in syntax error after expansion.