# does opencv has a definition for PI (3.14...)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am writting code that uses opencv and i need to have access to PI (3.14...), I know that standard math.h has the efinition, but I found it not easy to uses it is not exposed by default.

Does OpenCV has any definition for PI?

Comment: Note that the macro `M_PI` [is actually not standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5008376/256138).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. It defines `CV_PI`.

I think it's defined in the `cv` namespace.

Edit: At a closer [look](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/core_2include_2opencv2_2core_2types__c_8h_source.html) it seems that it's available in the global namespace.

Comment: Nice. Also it appears to be in [opencv2/hal/defs.h](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d64/defs_8h.html#a677b89fae9308b340ddaebf0dba8455f)

Comment: typically `CV_` means global namespace but most/many of them were changed to `cv` namespace in opencv 3.0 and got `CV_` removed afaik.

Comment: Actually `CV_PI` still is the way to go in OpenCV 3.0. `cv::PI` doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

In OpenCV python, it seems `CV_PI` (or `cv2.CV_PI`) doesn't exist, use `numpy.pi`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently CV_PI seems to be in cvdef.h, line 193:

[cvdef.h](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/cc1a95d161d08306462823de7ec6c50a3698d99c/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h)

[cvdef.h line 193](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/cc1a95d161d08306462823de7ec6c50a3698d99c/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h#L193)

```
#define CV_PI   3.1415926535897932384626433832795
```

I can confirm as others have mentioned that cv::PI does not seem to be available any longer (probably removed in the OpenCV 2 to OpenCV 3 change over when the OpenCV 1 legacy stuff was depreciated).