# Obtaining the decimal value of Cosinus phi

Tags: c

When I write on my calculator Cos45 I get a decimal number = 0.707

How do I produce such a number in C.

I tested this:

```
printf ("type a degree between 0 - 360:\n");
scanf ("%f",&float1);
printf ("cosphi = %f",cosf(float1));
```

but it gave an off number. It produced cosphi = 0.52

Comment: This is mentioned in all [references for `cosf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cos).

Answer (score 4):

Your calculator is configured to compute trigonometric functions in degrees.

C's trig functions work in radians. (A full circle is 360 degrees, 2*pi radians.)

If you want to treat the input as degrees, you need to convert the value to radians before passing it to `cosf()`, by multiplying it by 180/pi.

Comment: Thank you . something like this. find cos45. pi radians / 4 = 180 / 4. when I put : printf ("cosphi = %f",cosf(3.14/4)); the print is 0.707 that is correct .

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Thanks a million :)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
//Convert Trigonometric Angles into Decimals and Radians.
//Radians are number of Radiuses that are wrapped around the circumference.
//Pi for half the circle, Radius is wrapped 3.14 times on 180 degrees. r2=d1 .
//Circumference = 2radius * Pi = Diameter * Pi = 2Pi * radius .
//KHO2016.no2. mingw (TDM-GCC-32) . c-ansi .
{
//Declare
float flp1, flp2, flp3, flp4, pi;
int int1;

//valuate
pi = 3.141592654;
int1 = 180;

//calculate
printf ("type a degree between 0 - 360 : ");
scanf ("%f",&flp1);
flp2=int1/flp1;  // 180 is divided by desired angle
flp3=pi/flp2;    // Pi is divided by the result of 180 / desired angle = Radians
flp4=cosf(flp3); // Result of Pi divided by Radians and fed into the Cosf Radian modulus
printf ("The Decimal value of Cosinus %.1f degrees = %.3f\n",flp1,flp4);
printf ("Angle typed in Radians = %f",flp3);

//Terminate
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Consider using variable names that are more descriptive than "flp123".  Also, you can just use literal values like 3.141592 and 180 without assigning them to variables.

Comment: `double angle_deg;
scanf("%f", &angle_deg);
printf("cos %.1f deg = %f\n", angle_deg, cos(angle_deg * 180.0 / M_PI);`

Comment: If you `#include <math.h>` then you'll get M_PI.

Comment: @nibot `M_PI` is often included in `<math.h>`, but that is not specified to be there.  Still, `M_PI`, is a good idea when available.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5008376/2410359 for details.

Answer (score 0):

As answer well by [@Keith Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38687980/2410359), the C function works in radians and so a degrees to radian conversion is needed.

```
#ifndef M_PI
  #define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif
float angle_radians = angle_degrees * (float) (M_PI/180.0);
```

Yet rather that directly scale by `pi/180.0`, code will get more precise answers, for angles outside a primary range, if code first does range reduction and *then* scales by `pi/180.0`.  This is because the scaling of `pi/180.0` is inexact as machine pi `float pi = 3.14159265;` is not *exactly* mathematical π.  The radian range reduction, performed by `cos()`, is in error  as the computed radian value given to it is inexact to begin with.  With degrees, range reduction can be done *exactly*.

```
// Benefit with angles outside -360° to +360°
float angle_degrees_reduce = fmodf(angle_degrees, 360.0f);
float angle_radians = angle_degrees_reduce * M_PI/180.0;
```

[sind()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31525208/2410359) is a sine example that performs even better by reducing to a narrower interval. With angles outside the -45° to +45° range, there is benefit.