# How to convert rpm to rad/s in C?

Tags: c, vhdl, intel-fpga

How to convert rpm to rad/s in C? I am using Altera Monitor program to compute rad/s from rpm. but when i use 2*pi/60 it says "pi" is not declared.I have included math.h still it same issue.

also i have another problem when including vhdl floating point library. I am using Quatus 16.1 version. I tried to include

LIBRARY ieee;
use ieee.float_pkg.all;

Error (10481): VHDL Use Clause error at uart.vhd(27): design library "ieee_proposed" does not contain primary unit "float_pkg". Verify that the primary unit exists in the library and has been successfully compiled.

how to solve this?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions when tagging, `rpm` stands for Red Hat/RPM Package Manager!

Comment: I don't understand why you did not just type in the value for pi, or #define it.  Looking up the value of pi does not need an SO question!

Answer (score 3):

When using gcc (and many other compilers) the constant for pi is defined in `math.h` as [`M_PI`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html):

```
rads = rpm * 2.0 * M_PI / 60.0;
```

However this is not guaranteed by the C standard, so if your code needs to be portable then you should have a contingency definition for pi.

Comment: This is indeed not correct always, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007925/using-m-pi-with-c89-standard - while available in GlibC for example, *"These constants come from the Unix98 standard and were also available in 4.4BSD; therefore they are only defined if '_BSD_SOURCE' or '_XOPEN_SOURCE=500', or a more general feature select macro, is defined. The default set of features includes these constants."* I guess Altera uses GCC however.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: you may be right, but I've never encountered a situation where M_PI is not defined, for C at least (C++ is another matter).

Comment: `gcc pi.c -lm -pedantic -std=c11` for example

Comment: @PaulR : For Microsoft compilers the non-standard constants including `M_PI` are guarded by `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` which must be defined either globally or before including math.h (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6.aspx).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala :  The Altera NIOSII compiler is GCC with Newlib.  In Newlib's math.h, `M_PI` is guarded only by `__STRICT_ANSI__` (hence it is undefined when `-pedantic -std=c11` is used for example).  For portability it is perhaps easier to define your own constants.

Comment: Since 2 π / 60 ≈ 0.1047197551196597746154214461093167628066, you can also say *radians per second* ≈ 0.1047197551196597746154214461093167628066 × *rotations per minute*. The constant `0.1047197551196597746154214461093167628066` is correct to at least 128 bits of precision (computed using Maple), and should suffice for any ordinary purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The constant often defined in `math.h` is `M_PI` or sometimes `PI`, but not `pi`. But none of these constants are mentioned in the C standard, so you shouldn't rely on it and just define your own, e.g. using the name you expected:

```
#define pi 3.14159265358979323846
```