# sine wave generation in c++

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I am trying to generate a set of points, which when plotted as a graph represent a sine wave of 1 cycle. The requirements are :

- a sine wave of 1 cycle
- lower limit =  29491
- upper limit =   36043
- no of points = 100
- Amplitude = 3276
- zero offset = 32767

Code :

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("data.dat",ios::trunc | ios::out);
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        outfile << int(3276*sin(i)+32767) << "\n";
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I am generating and storing the points in a file. When these points are plotted I get the following graph.

[image]

But I only need one cycle. How can I do this?

Comment: What are "lower limit" and "upper limit"?

Comment: First of all you have to remember that [`std::sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) takes an *angle*. And that a full cycle is 360 degrees. And that [`std::sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) wants its angle in *radians* (i.e. a cycle is 2π degrees).

Comment: Read [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin): `arg  -  value representing angle in radians` - not just '0 to 100 and the computer will know what I really mean'

Comment: you miss to indicate the `wavelength`

Answer (score 10):

taking into the formula of [sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave):

> ```
> y(t) = A * sin(2 * PI * f * t + shift)
> ```
>
> where:
>
> A = the amplitude, the peak deviation of the function from zero.
>   f = the ordinary frequency, the number of oscillations (cycles)
>   t = time
>   shift = phase shift

would be:

```
y[t] = AMPLITUDE * sin (2 * M_PI * 0.15 * t + 0) + ZERO_OFFSET;
                                   ^^^ f = 15 cycles / NUM_POINTS = 0.15 Hz
```

To have one full-cycle, loop from `y[0:t)` where `t` is the time or number of points it takes to have a full cycle (i.e. wavelength)

Answer (score 3):

It appears you need 100 samples for one cycle, so you probably need this:

```
...
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
...
#define NB_OF_SAMPLES 100
...
  double angle = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < NB_OF_SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    outfile << int(3276 * sin(angle) + 32767) << "\n";
    angle += (2 * M_PI) / NB_OF_SAMPLES;
  }
...
```

Or better:

```
#define NB_OF_SAMPLES 100
#define OFFSET        3276
#define AMPLITUDE     32767

...
  double angle = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < NB_OF_SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    outfile << int(AMPLITUDE * sin(angle) + OFFSET) << "\n";
    angle += (2 * M_PI) / NB_OF_SAMPLES;
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A full cycle consists of 360 degrees. samples needed is 100. 
So step size is 3.6

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("data.dat",ios::trunc | ios::out);
    for(int i=0;i<101;i++)
    {
        float rads = M_PI/180;
        outfile << (float)(3276*sin(3.6*i*rads)+32767) << endl;
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

If number of samples is 200, then step size if `360/200 = 1.8`

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("data.dat",ios::trunc | ios::out);
    for(int i=0;i<201;i++)
    {
        float rads = M_PI/180;
        outfile << (float)(3276*sin(1.8*i*rads)+32767) << endl;
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The maths sine function [std::sin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) takes its argument in radians:

> arg   -   value representing angle in radians, of a floating-point or
>   Integral type

If you need 1 cycle and 100 points then, knowing that there are 2pi radians in one cycle, you need something like

```
double rads;
for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
    rads = 2.0*M_PI*i/100;
    // your expression in terms of std::sin(rads)
}
```

If, on the off chance your compiler/library doesn't have M_PI out of the box, then look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007925/using-m-pi-with-c89-standard) for flags that should make it available.

One thing that hasn't been touched on is the exact interval that you should generate. If you need the closed interval [0,2pi] then you will need to adjust your step sizes. I've given a half-open interval (0,2pi] and @Michael Walz has given the other half-open interval [0,2pi).

Comment: `/i` er, no. You mean `* (i / 100.0)`. I mean, the 1st iteration of what you wrote is instant UB!

Comment: Please note that `M_PI` is not a standard macro, not all libraries define it.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Have you ever used a compiler/library that didn't have it easily available?

Comment: I have seen it missing somewhere, but it was some time ago. However, considering that it's included with the MSVC headers and mandated by POSIX it's *almost* (but not quite) universal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the for loop to iterate from 0 to 2(pi).  That is one cycle for the sine wave.  You might also want to change the loop counter to a double instead of integer and increment by 0.1 or something instead.
[screenshot from WolframAlpha.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeAJk.png)