# How to make sine wave using defined frequency on Linux Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, sine-wave

i tried to make a tone using sine wave form on NASM x86_32, which i already define the frequency like this:

```
C: DW 4560
D: DW 4063
E: DW 3619
F: DW 3416
G: DW 3043
A: DW 2711
B: DW 2415
C.: DW 2280
```

I'm new on Linux assembly, i really appreciate all the help thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is:

`y(t) = A * sin(2 * PI * f * t + shift)`

(`A` is the amplitude, `f` the frequency (Given in Hz), `t` is the time, `shift` is the phase shift).

What will you need for mathematical operations?

You will need multiplication and sine.

I will give you a few hints:

For sine you can use [FSIN](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fsin), and for multiplication [FMUL](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fmul:fmulp:fimul). Furthermore in x86_32, all parameters are passed on the stack.
With this informations, you should be able to solve your task.

Source for sine wave:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50366375/13912132

Comment: Thanks @JCWasmx86... but i still doesn't understand how to calculate the for the y(t) in assembly.. can you broke down how i do it ? Thanks :)

Comment: @felixmontalfu How far did you get?

Comment: still figuring how i calculate sine wave, and how i push it to speaker driver

Comment: [Github](https://github.com/AFOEK/KeyPressASM/blob/master/key.asm) here on my GitHub sorry for the mess...:) @JCWasmx86