# Find the area of a circle using C language

Tags: c

I have to find the area of a circle using c, so I wrote this code. I'm getting the error `undefined reference to main`.

What I have tried:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float area(float r)
{
    float area;
    
    printf("\nEnter the radius of Circle : ");
    scanf("%f", &r);
    area = 3.14 * r * r;
    printf("\nArea of Circle : %f", area);

    return area;
}
```

Comment: What does your beginners book or tutorial say about `main`? It should have been explained in the very first chapter, when showing the very first example program.

Comment: In order to allow judging your level of experience, please tell us whether you ever succeeded in building and running a HelloWorld. Also please state whether you are doing your programming assignments for a special environment, especially a context in which the teacher provides a testing setup, with the core of the actual program, which will call the code you hand in for your assignments. Have you been provided with a version for your own environment? Are you expected to use a placeholder for the testing environment? Is there some code which you are supposed to always use?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hard coding the magic value 3.14 use a constant.  On my host math.h defines `M_PI` if `__USE_OPEN`, `__USE_MISC` or `__USE_GNU` are defined.  If your math.h doesn't you can define it like this:

```
#ifndef M_PI
#    define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif
```

The entry point for a hosted c program is the function `int main()` (or `int main(int, char *[])`.  This is your main problem.

`area()` takes a float r argument, but you populate that variable in in the function itself.  Either leave out the argument or as shown here let caller do the I/O and pass in the argument and return the result.

Always check the return value of `scanf()` otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized values.

Prefer trailing to leading `\n` as the output stream might be line buffered.

```
#define __USE_XOPEN
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float area(float r) {
    return M_PI * r * r;
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter the radius of Circle : ");
    float r;
    if(scanf("%f", &r) != 1) {
         printf("scanf failed\n");
         return 1;
    }
    printf("Area of Circle : %f\n", area(r));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every hosted `C` program has a primary function that must be named `main`. The `main` function serves as the starting point for program execution.

This program first reads the radius of the circle from the user, then calculates the area using the formula `area = pi * radius^2`. Finally, it prints the result.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  double radius;
  double area;

  // Read the radius of the circle from the user.
  printf("Enter the radius of the circle: ");
  if(scanf("%lf", &radius) != 1) // If user enter invalid stuff…
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: invalid input.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE; // EXIT_FAILURE means error.
  }

  // Calculate the area of the circle
  area = M_PI * radius * radius;

  // Print the result
  printf("The area of the circle is: %f.\n", area);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS; // EXIT_SUCCESS means success.
}
```

Comment: `M_PI` might [not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5008376/2410359).

Comment: What should the programmer do if `M_PI` is not defined in `<math.h>`?

Comment: Is `area = pi * radius^2` C code or mathematical notation? If it is C code, why does it use `pi` instead of the `M_PI` in the program, and why does it use `^2` instead of `radius * radius`? If it is mathematical notation, why does it use `pi` instead of π, and why does it use `^2` instead of a superscript 2?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `area = pi * radius^2` is the mathematical notation.